# pkcs11 support for kona 25 javacard

Tags: javacard, pkcs#11

I have some [Kona25](http://www.tagsystems.net/downloads/kona25.pdf) javacard from Tag systems and I want to use them for encryption and signature of my emails (for example in thunderbird).

I have searched Google, and I found that I need a PKCS11 module for my cards. I search more and I found that [Charismathics CSSI](http://www.charismathics.com/products/middleware-smart-security-interface/cssi/) provide a pkcs11 module for kona25 cards, but I am looking for an open source or free solution. Does anybody have a offer?

OpenSC doesn't support kona25 cards!

Comment: Why not extend OpenSC yourself, or donate some money/cards to get them supported? I presume you have the PKI applet installed, so you would need the interface specification for that.

Comment: Did you finished this project successfully?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a JavaCard, everything in OpenSC wiki about JavaCard-s applies. If it is a "blank" card, you need to get a PKI applet onto it and deal with everything related.

If you already have a PKI applet on the card and/or if you can't load your own applets (often the case with retailed javacards), you need to extend OpenSC to support it.

Comment: Thanks, I read that wiki again. My cards aren't blank. As I understand we have 2 approach to work with javacards:
1) load an applet on card, and use an host application to communicate with that applet.
2) use a pkcs#11 module for the card.
and OpenSC wiki offers first method. Do I understand well?
unfortunately, my company prefer method 2.
for method 1: I couldn't load Muscle applet to my cards. I had loaded [Java Card PKI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacardsign) applet to my cards, but it seems that OpenSC doesn't support it.
for method 2: how I can find a pkcs#11 module for my cards?