# Java Card not found by PC/SC or openSC

Tags: applet, javacard, pcsc, globalplatform

I've been trying to interact with a Java Card but so far I have not been successful.  I've downloaded openSC, GlobalPlatform, and I've been using PCSC for OS X. Running

> pcsctest

at the command line results in the following:

> MUSCLE PC/SC Lite Test Program
>
> Testing SCardEstablishContext    : Command successful.
>
> Testing SCardGetStatusChange
>
> Please insert a working reader   : Command successful.
>
> Testing SCardListReaders         : Command successful.
>
> Reader 01: Feitian R502 00 00
>
> Enter the reader number          : 01
>
> Waiting for card insertion

at which point it stops; I do have a card inserted into the reader.  Also, running

> opensc-tool -n

returns

> Card not present.

I have read this previous stackoverflow question: [pkcs11 support for kona 25 javacard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845383/pkcs11-support-for-kona-25-javacard/11879735#11879735) but I don't know how to find out if the card is blank, and load a PKI applet onto it if it is, if I cannot use any of the tools I've found to view the contents of a card.  Could anyone suggest why, or how I might find out why , none of these tools are noticing the card that I have inserted into the reader.
I'm using os x 10.9.2, a Feitian R502 reader whose product/vendor IDs I've added to the Info.plist in the ccid bundle, and a G+D smartcafe JavaCard.

Comment: opensc would show a card present even if it is a blank javacard. i think your problem lays somewhere between osx and pcsc. hav you tried on windows/linux?

Comment: I've tried windows but haven't gotten any better results that way.  Using globalplatform and running "gp.exe -list" or "gp.exe -list" just results in a blank line and a blinking cursor that stay that way until I close the command prompt.

Comment: @PaulBastian do you have any idea why os x might not be cooperating with pcsc?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct reader? This reader seems to be both contact and contactless, and normally those are seen as *separate* readers by the OS.

Comment: @pineapplevendor : did your problem solved or not? base on your another question (**creating .cap file**), I think your problem with the reader solved! if yes, please add an answer here that how you solved it!

Comment: @pineapplevendor If the problem haven't solved yet, please try **gp.exe** or **gpshell** or **gpj** on windows, and remember that, these tools have a incompatibility with **firefox** sometimes! so first, close firefox and kill `firefox.exe` process in **windows task manager**, then try to use that tools and share with us the response.

Answer (score 1):

Since posting the original question I have been able to use the reader after switching to a Linux system, downloading PCSC and CCID, Editing the ccid/readers/supported_readers.txt file to include "0x096E:0x060D:Feitian R502", and finally reinstalling CCID.  Since this I've been able to use GPshell to communicate with the card.